# Need content type for FormData

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am sending formData or Json to server. 
  So i need contentType for formData.
  Please don't give false as contentType value.

```
formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: formdata? formdata :$(#User).serialize(),                 
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    contentType: "json",
    processData: false,
    beforeSend: function () {
        $(options.createOrUpdateRelationship).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        var target = $(options.setupSubContainer);
        $("body").append(options.fadeoutDiv);
        options.spinner.spin(target[0]);
    },
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

Comment: whats wrong with `contentType: "application/json"` ?

Comment: contentType: "application/json not works

Comment: what do you mean by `'NOT WORKS'` ?

Comment: it pass null to controller as i am passing some values

Comment: try stringyfying the object and send in `data`

Comment: if stringyfying the formData, it gives blank json

Comment: how are you getting the data in the server side?

Answer (score 0):

Need to give the dataType because in which format sending data to server for example json,array
and you can give the formid.serialize() to to serialize the formadatas in a Query string format and send to server you can receive the data by $_POST in php

```
var form = $("#formId").serialize();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST'
url: url,
data: form,
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
   //add your code
}
});
```

contentType removed - we are not sending JSON.

Comment: its sending null, when i set it to false then only it is sending data of form data.  but if i make i false and in the situation of of $(#User).serialize() , it send null

Comment: hi try this http://devzone.co.in/jquery-serialize-function-ajax-post-bigger-html-forms/

Comment: Can you add some commentary to this answer to make it more usable?

Comment: @HemantMalpote: hi try the above code . remove the content type

Comment: when i remove contentType and send formData it doesn't works. i.e it send null at server side.