# Cannot get value of text field of form which is submitted through ajax inside submit handler

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to get the value of textbox that has been submitted through ajax, but when i try to get its value inside controller method it return nothing.

**Here is my AJAX function and controller method:**

```
  jQuery("#frm_xyz").validate({
      rules: {
          otp: {
              required: true
          },
      ....
      ....
      submitHandler: function(form,event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var from_url=jQuery(form).attr('action');
          jQuery.ajax({
              url: from_url, 
              type: "POST",             
              data: new FormData(document.getElementById("frm_xyz")),
              cache: false,             
              processData: false,      
              success: function(data) {
              }
          });
      }
  });
```

> **HTML:**

```
 <?php echo form_open('verify-verification-otp',array('id'=>"frm_xyz")); ?> 
     <input type="text" name="otp" placeholder="OTP" class="form-control" />
     <br />  
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn_verify_contact" class="btn btn-info" value="Verify OTP" />  
 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

but when i try to get value of textbox in controller i don't get the value!

> **PHP:**

```
public function verify_otp()
{
    $otp = $this->input->post('otp');
    print_r($otp);
    die();
}
```

Comment: You have to pass form serialize data in your ajax post data like `data: form.serialize()`. Please structure your code properly..

Comment: after this line - `var from_url=jQuery(form).attr('action');`, please print `from_url` what's value in it. I think it is blank because you didn't define it.

Comment: Also on submit, you can check the network tab if dev tools. It will show you the URL where the request is submitting with the value of inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to a number of reasons -

1. Set the form method to `POST` -

   ```
   <?php 
      echo form_open('verify-verification-otp',array('id'=>"frm_xyz", 'method'=>"POST"));
   ?>
   ```
2. Set `contentType` to `false` while sending formData or jquery default will overwrite it. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421527/formdata-object-not-working-with-jquery-ajax-post)

   ```
    jQuery.ajax({
           url: from_url,
           type: "POST",
           data: new FormData(document.getElementById("frm_xyz")),
           cache: false,
           processData: false,
           contentType: false, 
           success: function(data) {
                    }
       })
   ```
3. You don't need formData as you are not sending any file, just use
   `serialize` and you should be good to go. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123238/need-content-type-for-formdata)

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
       url: from_url,
       type: "POST",
       data: $('#frm_xyz').serialize(),
       cache: false,
       dataType: 'JSON',
       success: function(data) {
                }
   })
   ```

See if it helps you.